# How to get like count value from response?

Tags: json, retrofit

```
{
    "count": 1,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "likecount": 0,
            "unlikeCount": 0,
            "shareCount": 0,
            "i_id": 297,
            "p_id": 297,
            "name": "Airport  runways  columbia  hon",
            "description": "Airport  runways  columbia  hongkong  aviation  airplanes  aeroplanes",
            "c_id": 1,
            "status_id": 1,
            "source_id": 149,
            "date_created": null,
            "parentinfograph": "Staffing insurance  liability  ",
            "internal_url": "http://167.99.86.81:8000/media/DQ297.jpg",
            "external_url": "http://www.aertecsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Infographic-Runway-ENG.jpg",
            "mt_id": 1,
            "mtcode": "Business"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Is the above object your response and you want to get its `count` field?

Comment: I want like count ,unlike count and share count value from response from result list.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, create a POJO class from JSON string using :

http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Then, create an instance of POJO class. Now, using GSON, you can set the values in the instance. Lastly, you can get the value using getter method

For eg.

```
Usermodel usermodel = new Gson().fromJson(<JSON string>, UserModel.class);
```

Usermodel is my POJO class here.

Comment: I want like count ,unlike count and share count value from response from result list

Comment: Yes, you can get all the values from JSON using this method.

Comment: Please give me idea to get response of result data not knowing how to get using gson

Comment: {
    "count": 13,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "like_Flag": true,
            "unlike_Flag": true,
            "bookmark_Flag": false,
            "share_Flag": true,
            "uau_id": 317,
            "u_id": 6,
            "device_id": "f4:f5:db:bc:7:d3",
            "infograph": 265
        }
    ]
} How to save result value using retrofit gson

Answer (score 0):

```
Please check below:

    @Test
    public void getlikecount() {
        String JSON = "{\r\n" + 
                "    \"count\": 1,\r\n" + 
                "    \"next\": null,\r\n" + 
                "    \"previous\": null,\r\n" + 
                "    \"results\": [\r\n" + 
                "        {\r\n" + 
                "            \"likecount\": 0,\r\n" + 
                "            \"unlikeCount\": 0,\r\n" + 
                "            \"shareCount\": 0,\r\n" + 
                "            \"i_id\": 297,\r\n" + 
                "            \"p_id\": 297,\r\n" + 
                "            \"name\": \"Airport  runways  columbia  hon\",\r\n" + 
                "            \"description\": \"Airport  runways  columbia  hongkong  aviation  airplanes  aeroplanes\",\r\n" + 
                "            \"c_id\": 1,\r\n" + 
                "            \"status_id\": 1,\r\n" + 
                "            \"source_id\": 149,\r\n" + 
                "            \"date_created\": null,\r\n" + 
                "            \"parentinfograph\": \"Staffing insurance  liability  \",\r\n" + 
                "            \"internal_url\": \"http://167.99.86.81:8000/media/DQ297.jpg\",\r\n" + 
                "            \"external_url\": \"http://www.aertecsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Infographic-Runway-ENG.jpg\",\r\n" + 
                "            \"mt_id\": 1,\r\n" + 
                "            \"mtcode\": \"Business\"\r\n" + 
                "        }\r\n" + 
                "    ]\r\n" + 
                "}";

         JsonPath jsonpath = new JsonPath(JSON);
         System.out.println("value of key->likecount: "+jsonpath.getString("results.likecount[0]"));



    }

Output: value of key->likecount: 0
```